# Can't pull image from docker repo

Tags: docker

I'm trying `sudo docker pull ubuntu` on Docker 1.13.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and getting error:

```
Error response from daemon: manifest for ubuntu:latest not found
```

I don't use proxy so I have no idea where manifest got lost.

Comment: I think there is some issue with the dockerhub at this moment. I just tried in multiple ways and getting timeout error. Its a temporary issue

Comment: From their [Tweets](https://twitter.com/dockerstatus/status/836645881516457984), looks to be an issue with Docker services: [http://status.docker.com/](http://status.docker.com/)

Comment: Likely this is related to the AWS S3 / EC2 issues today.

Comment: Same here. It's really bad, since I cannot develop any further without access to the Hub. Docker really needs to get rid of these kind of errors, otherwise it does not make sense to use it in production.

Comment: Same here. I don't think they've fixed this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be an outage incident, which is probably outside of the scope of technical Q&A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it just started working 3 hours later without any intervention, so I make a conclusion that the problem was caused by [Docker Hub incident](https://twitter.com/dockerstatus/status/836645881516457984).

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by S3 outage, see [docker- issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/31430).

For some reason Docker haven't noticed yet, according to [status](https://status.docker.com/).

Funny thing is that one can see other services unavailable like GitHub or Travis CI.